# magento subdomain website $this->getRequest()->isPost() return blank in every form submission

Tags: magento-1.8, forms, nginx, multidomain, form-key

I have magento website in domain and also in sub domain.

The domain website form work correctly i.e. `$this->getRequest()->isPost()` return true after form submission.

But the subdomain website form after submission `$this->getRequest()->isPost()` return false.

I also add the code : getFormKey(); ?>" />

after form tag then also it is not working.`$this->getRequest()->isPost()` return false.

Same code works in my local xampp server.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

> $this->getRequest()->isPost()

and not

> $this->getrequest()->ispost()

Comment: Sorry..its $this->getRequest()->isPost() in my code also.Its just change in my question now i just edit with proper name in question.

Comment: $this->getRequest()->isPost() this method returns blank.Please help me..

Comment: Are you getting anything in $this->getRequest()->getPost() ?

Comment: $this->getRequest()->isPost()  return true if $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'

Comment: Sir its working fine in xampp server localhost but after uploaded to server in subdomain magento website its not work.I didn't get any value in $this->getRequest()->isPost() method neither true nor false. i'm so stuck with this issue.

Comment: i don't think subdomain create this issue.check your form is correct and is posting.

Comment: check with simply print_r($_POST)

Comment: if your form is posting data ,$this->getRequest()->isPost()  must return true

Comment: This is my code i did but it return nothing.. ' if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
           // $this->_redirectReferer();
            return;
        }
        $session = $this->_getSession();
        echo "1".$this->getRequest()->isPost()."2";
        $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
        var_dump($login);
        die;
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
   var_dump($login); '

Comment: check with simply print_r($_POST)

Comment: after  print_r($_POST) it returns me Array ( )

Comment: now check your form method is post and all elements are present in <form></form>

Comment: Sir...this same form is work in my localhost server no change in code.its only not work in hosted server.

Comment: make sure everything in live is same as localhost

Comment: there is difference of server like I'm using apache in xampp but in server side nginx server is use

Comment: my start of the form is : '<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate">
     <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
     <div class="fieldset">
            <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?php echo $this->getSuccessUrl() ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?php echo $this->getErrorUrl() ?>" />
            <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Personal Information') ?></h2>' like this

Comment: I also enable log in magento but there is no error shown after posting form.

Comment: check .htaccess file

Comment: that might be creating issue for subdomain

Comment: your site is on https or http ?

Comment: Sir, In hosted server..nginx server is use. Acc. to me nginx server has no relation to .htaccess file.its only related to apache

Comment: http my https certificate are expire.. my website in on http

Comment: one possible reason is only that

Comment: if your site is on http and your form post on https or site is on https and your form post on http than htaccess rule redirect it to proper protocol

Comment: check with server guys

Comment: sir...I want to know you that I already have magento website on my domain with same code with same form and it works fine. So I thought there is no posting problem with htaccess has in both websites i.e. domain and subdomain .htaccess file is same throughout.

Comment: wondering now...

Comment: sir...thx for your lot of help has pblm not yet solve...sir can you know me the exact tutorial of magento form posting detail ...so that it can help me to go in deep about this..

Comment: the proper flow after submission of form..right now my form .phtml file in 'app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml'

Comment: i don't think any issue with form now

Comment: do one thing create sample php file witch contain sample form data and post that form on your sub domain  and check what is going on there

Comment: form in sample php or magento extension that contains form and posting...

Comment: I also have normal form which is not related magento i.e. not under magento folder. That form is working fine.This is form is on subdomain only.

Comment: Sir is there any session issue after posting the form in magento so that $this->getRequest()->isPost()  is blank

Comment: track and solve that issue then

Comment: sir..just one help..can u suggest how this session related with form post in magento..any tutorial...how can I track I'm stuck with it..

Comment: what is issue with session ?

Comment: sir..I just thought there is some issue with session or cookie.I google on this issue so i found this same issue and problem in cookie and session.But I don't know the relation of cookie and seesion after posting form.So can you know me how session and cookie role after posting the form.

Comment: @AshikLanjewar found issue and solution ?

Comment: yes sir...its issue from server side of redirection in nginx server.we just change config file of nginx server and solve it.